# PHP Row Checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox, row, rows

I want to make a Row with Checkbox. 
If the checkbox is not checked and you check the value is changed in SQL and the reverse too.

I have this:

```html
<?php

if ($Row['vip'] == 1)
     {
      echo "<td style='text-align: center;' width='5%'><input type='checkbox' name='vip[]' value='1' checked='checked' /></td>";
     }
     else
     {
      echo "<td style='text-align: center;' width='5%'><input type='checkbox' name='vip[]' value='0' /></td>";
     }
?>
```

Checkbox.php

```html
<?php
 require('config.php');

 $iConnection = mysqli_connect($_HOST_,$_USER_,$_PASS_,$_MYDB_) or die("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css'><h4>Rank not found.</h4>");
 
 if($checkbox1 = $_POST['vip'];
 {
 for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkbox1);$i++)
 $query="INSERT INTO mytable (vip) VALUES ('".$checkbox1[$i]."')";
 mysqli_query($iConnection, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
 }
 echo "Record is inserted";
 }
?>
```

Comment: For one thing, you're assigning here `if($checkbox1 = $_POST['vip'];` rather than comparing. However, that isn't the right syntax and that semi-colon is stopping your code from further executing. Not to mention the missing bracket.

Comment: I want update mytable every time i click in one checkbox to check it or uncheck it.